# Mapping object list as component to different tables in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My team and I are trying to map a legacy database to a newer domain model(1) using NHibernate. In this domain model we have a common class used as a component in two different classes (VehicleOwned and VehicleRented both have a VehicleOrigins-component). Both classes have their own table in the database and map fields from their table onto the common class. We now want to add a collection to the common class (PreviousOwners). Due to the structure of the database we need to support mapping this to two different tables (a VehicleOwnedPreviousOwners and a VehicleRentedPreviousOwners-table), but we would like to expose this as a single class and deal with the differences in the mapping. We map the new collection class (PreviousOwners) in an own mapping file for the properties and can set the table in the component mapping and thus far everything works.

The problem we are facing is that the Id-column in the table differs in name between the two tables and there is no obvious way to declare the id in the mapping. Is there a way for NHibernate to support this scenario?

```
//the two classes that share a common component
class VehicleOwned
{
    public int VehicleOwnedId { get; set; }
    //...
    public VehicleOrigins Origins;
}

class VehicleRented
{
    public int VehicleRentedId { get; set; }
    //...
    public VehicleOrigins Origins;
}

//the component
class VehicleOrigins
{
    public string OriginalPaintJob { get; set; }
    //...
    public IList<PreviousOwner> PreviousOwners { get; set; }
}

//the class in the component that maps to two different tables
class PreviousOwner
{
    public int PreviousOwnerId { get; set; } //the column name for this id differs in both tables
    public string Name { get; set; } //the regular properties share the same column name across the tables
    //...
}

//the map for the class in the component
class PreviousOwnerMap : ClassMap<PreviousOwner>
{
    public PreviousOwnerMap()
    {
        //cannot map table here because it depends on the parent class
        //cannot map id here because it depends on the table which depends on the parent class
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("name");
    }
}

//the map for the classes, with a map to the component
class VehicleOwnedMap : ClassMap<VehicleOwned>
{
    public VehicleOwnedMap()
    {
        Table("VehicleOwned");
        Id(x => x.VehicleOwnedId).Column("VehicleOwnedId");
        Component(x => x.Origins, f => {
            f.Map(x => x.OriginalPaintJob).Column("OriginalPaintJob");
            f.HasMany(x => x.PreviousOwners)
                .Table("VehicleOwnedPreviousOwners");
                //can map the table, not the ID...
        });
    }
}

class VehicleRentedMap : ClassMap<VehicleRented>
{
    public VehicleRentedMap()
    {
        Table("VehicleRented");
        Id(x => x.VehicleRentedId).Column("VehicleRentedId");
        Component(x => x.Origins, f =>
        {
            f.Map(x => x.OriginalPaintJob).Column("OriginalPaintJob");
            f.HasMany(x => x.PreviousOwners)
                .Table("VehicleRentedPreviousOwners");
                //can map the table, not the ID...
        });
    }
}
```

(1) This is a fictional and intentionally simplified example that serves the purpose of this question. And no, we can't change the model OR database either, unfortunately.